# How to convert a PDF with a filled form to a JPEG image using ImageMagick and preserving the form data?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, jpeg, ghostscript, pdf-conversion

I'm trying to convert this PDF to a JPEG image via ImageMagick (v 6.8.7-0): https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10351891/cd.pdf

I didn't find any working solution to preserve the filled data inside the PDF.
This is one of the commands tried:

`convert -colorspace CMYK -alpha off -interlace none -density 300x300 -quality 100 cd.pdf[0] cd_image.jpg`

Since ImageMagick use Ghostscript for the conversion I've also update it to the last version (v 9.10) but nothing changed.

The command always print out a few warnings:

`"Warning: considering '0000000000 XXXXX n' as a free entry"`

`"/BBox has zero width or height, which is not allowed."`

Did someone find a way to convert it?

More information:

I used Preview for Mac to fill out the form.

On production, we use Ubuntu not Mac OS X and the PDF is not filled by me, but It's sent to us prefilled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue that Max OS X PDF Preview does not support AcroForms properly, see this blog post that contains some details: [Script to Fix Mac OSX Preview.app Form Fill and Save](http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/2009/11/script_to_fix_mac_osx_previewa.html).

Among other errors, your PDF form fields have a missing piece of information: the appearance stream (a set of instructions that tell the viewer how the field value is supposed to be rendered when it is not being edited).

If you can specify which PDF viewer should be used for editing the forms, then avoid Mac OS X preview. If you need to support Mac OS X preview, then you can try to re-generate this information programmatically with any PDF library that allows filling out forms, or you can apply a form flattening process instead (converting the "dynamic" text into static) before exporting as jpeg.

Examples:

- If you have access to a Windows box and Adobe Acrobat, you can try
  with the script mentioned before.
- If you have access to a Windows box and purchasing a commercial
  library is an option, you can try with [Amyuni PDF
  Creator](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex/)
  (Disclaimer: I work for Amyuni Technologies). for regenerating the
  appearance stream you will need to enumerate the form fields,
  retrieve their values, set an empty value to them, then re-assign
  them the original values. For doing form flattening, you will have to
  set the annotation attribute of each form field to false.
- If you have access to a Linux box and a library with a GPL license is
  not an issue, you can try creating a Java application with iText, the
  method
  [PdfStamper.setFormFlattening(boolean)](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html#setFormFlattening%28boolean%29)
  seems to do what you need.

Comment: I used Preview for Mac to fill out the form. Any idea how to regenerate the information programmatically or how to apply a form flattening process?

Comment: I tried to export the PDF to PS (with pdftops) and then back to PDF (with ps2pdf) but didn't work. pdftops fails with this syntax error: "Unknown font in field's DA string"

Comment: @Panda, the syntax errors/warnings with this file are real, it has severe issues, so better don't use same method with other files - the damage may be unpredictable and at the time you least expecting. *Preview for Mac*? H-mm..

Comment: @VadimR, do you know how can I fix those severe issues programmatically?

Comment: @yms On production, we use Ubuntu not Mac OS X and the PDF is not filled by me, but It's sent to us prefilled :(

Comment: @Panda, to answer your question: Policy towards broken PDF files is *open at any cost, show at least something, use heuristics* etc. It's good until it hurts you, with expensive job that opens wrong. If application is capable of doing what we've seen on one example, who knows what it'll do with another file? That being said, if it's OK with you, issues (3 mentioned above, don't know about others) don't need to be fixed manually, many applications ignore them or fix them silently. The question is, then, as yms says, how to build AP (appearance) of variable text fields.

Comment: And for that, a simple method (to add to yms's) is `pdftk`'s `need_appearances` option - then at least Reader opens PDF with filled fields, and, note, asks to save on close. Then adding `OpenAction` to file's `Catalog` -- JS to save and close -- can be poor man's automation. Though adding it programmatically is about as difficult, for me, as adding AP's for simple text strings.